# React Fetch Double url

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

[How the code looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n1KS.png)

[And for some reason I get my react localhost:3000 and my api url in the response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mckZu.png)

Why?

Comment: You've missed the : in https:// in baseURL.

Comment: this is correct. THANKS!

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question, and not hidden behind some links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have missed semicolon in your `baseUrl` constant so it treats it as relative path